# Getting Python to print pretty date strings?

Tags: python, date, calendar

How can I get Python to output

'Mon Jun 04'
'Tue Jun 05'

etc, for a week of given time?

ex

```
today = datetime.datetime.today()
### do some magic
days = ['Tue Jun 05',...]
```

What do I do with 'today' to generate the results? I'm not even sure if I'm the right module, calender seems to share similar features.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
days = [today.strftime("%a %b %y"), ...]
```

We use strftime to take a datetime object and format it to a string

http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `strftime` method of datetime objects.